# python 3.4 mod_wsgi error installing

Tags: c++, django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm having a heck of a time trying to install mod_wsgi for apache 2.4 / python 3.4 right now.  I've been looking at some other answers but don't seem to be helping.  I set up a virtual environment and attempted:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

to start the process, but I keep getting an error:

> Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi'
>   extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with
>   "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1":
>   www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Some people mentioned the easiest remedy is to install the visual studio community edition, but I already have Visual Studio 2017 installed.  I also checked my installations and I have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 and x86 Redistirbutables installed.

edit: I also attempted to go to the link that was provided and install the windows sdk, after which there was still no fix

Edit 2:

Path environment variables:

```
E:\platforms\python3.4.4\;
E:\platforms\python3.4.4\Scripts;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
E:\platforms\jdk8u172\bin;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;
E:\platforms\python3.6.5\Scripts\;
E:\platforms\python3.6.5;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
E:\Git\cmd;
E:\Git\mingw64\bin;
E:\Git\usr\bin;
C:\Program Files\dotnet\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;
E:\TortoiseGit\bin;
%GROOVY_HOME%\bin;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;
E:\platforms\node10.1.0\;
E:\IDE\vs2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build;
```

Comment: What're the directories in your `PATH` variable?

Comment: I do have it in the non-standard place, you are thinking that it's not included in the path environment variable?

Comment: @Aziz which folder should I look to link in path?

Comment: Yes, do you mind sharing the output of `echo %PATH%`, or at least making sure that VC++ SDK is in there.

Comment: you are correct, it doesn't look like I have anything vc++ related in there.  would i be looking to add the path to vcvarsall or something else?

Comment: @Aziz updated with paths

Comment: It is super critical you get the exact right compiler for the Python version as noted in https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers. Also just as important and where people often get tripped up, is that all components, Apache, Python and compiler, must be all 64 bit or all 32 bit. Too many times seen people actually have 32 bit compiler but 64 bit Python, which will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what was going on, I tried installing the Windows SDK from the link and it also provided errors.  I decided to just up to python 3.6.5 and it seems to have installed mod_wsgi correctly